# Determine the expected run times of an SQL agent within a timeframe

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-agent-job

Is there a reliable way of determining what times a given sql agent will run within a given timeframe?

I have a `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.Job` object but want to avoid having to re-create the logic to calculate run times based on its schedules. I'm hoping that there is some built in functionality for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there isn't. And it's more complicated to detect this when your job has multiple schedules.

However, for the simple case when you have just 1 schedule, I think you can do the following:

- Query the job for its `NextRunDate`
- Set the schedule's [`ActiveStartDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobschedule.activestartdate.aspx) to the next run date.
- Repeat until you cover your interval.
- At the end make sure to set `ActiveStartDate` to its initial value.

You can do this only once, when the job is created, and persist the results. Thus you eliminate the risk of modifying the job each time you need to evaluate the run time (because changing the ActiveStartDate will actually modify the schedule).

Comment: Nice thinking outside the box! Note sure I like the fact that it adjusts the schedule, but looks as good as I'm going to get without manually re-creating the scheduler's logic.